# AG Grid tooltip takes long time to render

Tags: reactjs, tooltip, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I was following [this example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tooltip-component/) and found out that the table takes quite some time to render the tooltip. It doesn't seem to have any delay whatsoever, and I have tried both defaultBrowserTooltip as well as the custom one but both of them are slow. Any given tips on this?

P/S: I'm using React

Some way that I have tried:

```
tooltipField: 'myTooltipField'

tooltip: (value: string): string => value
```

Comment: instead of putting a bounty on this, you may want to reconsider and provide an MVCE (see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This might also help you understand the problem a bit better. As it is now, there is simply nothing to go on. The problem could be anything, including hell of a slow developer machine...

Comment: @konqi The issue is present in the linked library demo page, not inherent to a specific set-up.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As of Ag-grid 23.0.0, this is configurable by the [`tooltipShowDelay` configuration option](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grid-properties/#miscellaneous).

```
const gridOptions = {
  tooltipShowDelay: 0; // milliseconds, default value 2000ms
};
```

For earlier versions, Ag-grid used an internal service called `TooltipManager` which was [not configurable](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/3225).
The default delay was 2 seconds:

```
private readonly MOUSEOVER_SHOW_TOOLTIP_TIMEOUT = 2000;
```

For these earlier versions, you could manually get the service reference from the bean bag and override it, but for versions 23.0.0 and up this is not necessary.

```
private onGridReady(params: GridReadyEvent) {
    // NB! This is unsupported and may break at any time
    try {
      (params.api as any).context.beanWrappers.tooltipManager.beanInstance.MOUSEOVER_SHOW_TOOLTIP_TIMEOUT = 0;
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works.  Another problem I'm facing is, there seems to be no delay at all after the initial appearance.  So if I set the delay to 500ms, this only works for the first time.  When I move my mouse over to another element with tooltip, it will display immediately instead of delaying for 500ms.  Which is annoying.  Do you know if theres a solution to this as well?

Comment: @FeCH Haven't looked into it myself since we didn't need that usage, you can check out [the tooltipManager.ts source](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/master/packages/ag-grid-community/src/ts/widgets/tooltipManager.ts#L81) for more implementation details.

Comment: it is deprecated in v23.0

Comment: how about this issue? do you know any solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62047444/ag-grid-keep-open-tooltip-for-a-certain-predefined-time

Answer (score 5):

This is directly "borrowed" from user demostheneslld who commented on the ag-grid [GitHub feature request](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/3225), but you can set `enableBrowserTooltips: true` on the grid options object and then the tooltips will be displayed natively by the browser, rather than formatted by ag-grid. The tooltips then appear almost instantly.

Comment: Did not work for me on chrome. It just changed the style of the tooltip, but still seemed to take ~2seconds.

Answer (score 5):

There is now a property for this called `tooltipShowDelay`, it was included in version 23.0.0 released on march 17th 2020. Docs https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-properties/#miscellaneous and changelog https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-changelog/?fixVersion=23.0.0

Answer (score 1):

There is a new prop released now:

```
tooltipShowDelay={0}
```

this above code will show tooltip instantly.
[More Info](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tooltip-component/#:%7E:text=Tooltip%20Show%20Delay,which%20is%20set%20in%20milliseconds.)