# Ag-grid: keep open tooltip for a certain predefined time

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using Ag-grid v23.1.1

I need to show a tooltip for 1 minute.

Ag grid does not support this case
But earlier in version 22 I have used next lifehack

```
params.api.context.beanWrappers.tooltipManager.beanInstance.MOUSEOVER_SHOW_TOOLTIP_TIMEOUT = 0;
params.api.context.beanWrappers.tooltipManager.beanInstance.DEFAULT_HIDE_TOOLTIP_TIMEOUT = 60000;
params.api.context.beanWrappers.tooltipManager.beanInstance.MOUSEOUT_HIDE_TOOLTIP_TIMEOUT = 3000;
```

But in the current version (23) `tooltipManager` has been removed.

And we have `TooltipFeature`
https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/master/community-modules/core/typings/widgets/tooltipFeature.d.ts

In new version names has been changed to:

```
 DEFAULT_HIDE_TOOLTIP_TIMEOUT;
    SHOW_QUICK_TOOLTIP_DIFF;
    FADE_OUT_TOOLTIP_TIMEOUT;
```

The same approach is not valid

Do you know any lifehacks in the current version?

Comment: Instead of hacking the non-public internals of the grid, which inevitably leads to breakage on version changes, you might want to consider writing a custom CellRenderer that puts up a tooltip so that you can implement the tooltip the way that you want to.